# Change days to int without pandas in python

Tags: python, for-loop, datetime

Is there any way to convert the resulting days into INT without pandas? Or use the number of days to do "for" loop?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=10) 
date = datetime.today() - d

print(date)
```

Result:

```
10 days, 0:00:00
```

If I try for loop, it doesn't work.

```
for days in range(date):
    print("■")
```

Error:

```
line 16, in <module>
    for i in range(date):
TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Newb, thank you.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! when asking python questions, make sure to add the `python` tag, and if you don't want pandas answers, don't add that tag ;) see the [guide to tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subtract two `datetime.datetime` objects, the result is a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). Check out the linked docs page for more information. From the docs:

> Instance attributes (read-only):
>
> | Attribute | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | `days` | Between -999999999 and 999999999 inclusive |
> | `seconds` | Between 0 and 86399 inclusive |
> | `microseconds` | Between 0 and 999999 inclusive |

Accessing the `.days` attribute gives the number of days as an integer.

So your example should look something like this:

```py
In [1]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta
   ...:
   ...: delta = timedelta(days=10)

In [2]: for days in range(delta.days):
   ...:     print(days)
   ...:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: "for days in range(date.days):" worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could try

"astype"

```
date = date.astype(int)
```

Comment: this doesn't work with timedelta objects: `AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: You said you aren't using Pandas, are you using numpy?

Comment: the OP imports datetime and timedelta from the builtin datetime library - see `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`